# How do I counter iframe security problems?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, xhtml

I heard there are many security issues that could arise when you use iframes. I already handle XSS, what else should I do to make sure no problems happen?

I came across some JS codes where you use top.window, but my concern is that any client-side code is not reliable, anything else I can do from the server side? (I am currently using php, but would be awesome if the solution is generic)

UPDATE: to make things clearer, I am actually using an iframe, its just because I don't want the headers, menues etc.. to be refreshed every time. So I am trying to find a way to use iframe without falling into security problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header to deny. This will let the browsers know that if the resource is loaded via iframe then don't display.

You can read more about this & configuring the server to send this header @ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header). Also, you in PHP you can use

```
header("X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY")
```